# Add dispatch.yaml to each of the services?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am running a couple of services in GAP and I have to assign each service a specific subdomain, which is done from the dispatch.yaml file. So far so good, my query is: Is it enough to define the dispatch.yaml file in a single service or do I have to do it for each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign all services to specific subdomains using a single `dispatch.yaml` file:

```yaml
- url: "subdomain1.domain.com/*"
  service: service1

- url: "subdomain2.domain.com/*"
  service: service2

- url: "subdomain3.domain.com/*"
  service: service3

#And so on
```